# Unable to set texture in constructor

Tags: c#, xna

I have a problem with source `Rectangle` and because of this my texture does not show on the screen.
When I use Draw method with source as null the texture works.

I have no idea what is wrong with this.

Also if I put this into the constructor: `source=new Rectangle((int)position.x,(int)position.Y, texture.Width/frameas, texture.Height)`. I get the error

> "use *new* keyword to create an object"

There is no error in my Game1 for sure as I only load texture,update, and draw in there.

```
public class Player
{
    public Texture2D texture;
    public Vector2 position;
    public int speed, width,frames, jump;
    public float scale;
    public Vector2 velocity;
    public float gravity;
    public bool hasJumped;
    public Rectangle source;



    public Player(int x, int y)
    {
        speed = 5;
        position.X = x;
        position.Y = y;
        scale = 1.8f;
        frames = 4;
        source = new Rectangle(x,y, 30,30);


    }

    public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
    {
        texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("player");
    }
    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        position += velocity;
        KeyboardState keyState = Keyboard.GetState();
        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
        {
            velocity.X = 3f;
        }
        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
        {
            velocity.X = -3f;
        }
        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) && hasJumped==false)
        {
            position.Y -= 10f;
            velocity.Y = -5f;
            hasJumped = true;
        }
        if (hasJumped == true)
            velocity.Y += 0.15f;
        else
            velocity.Y = 0f;
    }
    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, source, Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, scale, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide some more detail on the error you described with `new` keyword in constructor? Also please post the size of player texture and the resulting source rectangles you expect (and what you actually get) in Player constructor.

Comment: source=new Rectangle((int)position.x,(int)position.Y, (int)texture.Width/frameas, (int)texture.Height)

Comment: @JackGajanan that can be found in the question, and I asked for **some more detail** on it.

Comment: Might it be the problem if I make the rectangle bigger than the texture itself?(I dont think so). About this new keyword error it occurs only if I change the line source = new Rectangle(x,y, 30,30); with source=new Rectangle((int)position.x,(int)position.Y, texture.Width/frameas, texture.Height)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reference `texture` within your constructor because it doesn't exist yet.  It's not set to an actual value until you load the texture in `LoadContent()`, so when you try to use it to build your rectangle it's throwing a `NullReferenceException`.

Create your source rectangle after this line:

```
texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("player");
```

Comment: You are right about this but still It doesnt show the texture on the screen. Lets say my texture (tile sheet) size is 100/50 have 2 frames in it and I wanna display first one. I created:
Rectangle source=new Rectangle((int)position.X,(int)position.Y,texture.Width/frames,texture.Height)
(like i did in the code above) and its not showing the texture at the screen which is weird because it should work

Comment: What is the value of `position`?  You appear to be using it to mean two different things:  the sprite's position on the texture, and the player's position on the screen.

Comment: position= players position on the screen.. lets say its (100,100)

Comment: Then you're creating your source rectangle incorrectly.  The x, y coordinates of the source rectangle should be the sprite's position on the texture.  What happens if you set them to 0, 0?

Comment: Wow it works now thank you very much now I get it. I was thinking it was the coordinates of the position of a player not the sprite position in texture. Once again thx